# Object is possibly null even with the guard check

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

Hello I have a problem I am getting the `Object is possibly "null"` probably because I handle this check by the generic error handler in nodejs + express. How can I solve it?

REST API

```
export const getOrderRaport = async (
  req: Request<{}, {}, IAuthUser>,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction,
) => {
  const orderId = req.query.orderId;
  const order = await Order.findOne({ orderId: orderId });
  if (!order) next(createError("Order does not exist"));
  const orderUser = await User.findOne({ userId: order.userId });
  const requestUser = await User.findOne({ userId: req.body.userId });
  if (!orderUser) next(createError("Order was not found for the specified user"));
  if (!requestUser) next(createError("You are not allowed to view this order"));
  if (orderUser._id != requestUser._id) {
  }
};
```

error handler

```
 app.use((error: CustomError, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
      const status = error.status || 500;
      const message = error.message || 'Something went wrong';
      res.status(status).json({message});
    });
```

Comment: Where does the error occur?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "guard check" or guard clause should exit the function/block early so that execution doesn't move on to the next line. This can be done using either `return` or `throw` (or `continue`/`break` in loops).

> ```
> if (!order) next(createError("Order does not exist"));
> ```

Should be:

```
if (!order) return next(createError("Order does not exist"));
```

To return the `next()` result from `getOrderRaport()` (wrapped in a promise).

Or:

```
if (!order) {
  next(createError("Order does not exist"));
  return;
}
```

To return `undefined` as the promise result.

Alternatively you can reject the promise returned from `getOrderRaport()` by throwing an error, which also halt execution of any further lines in the function.

```
if (!order) {
  next(createError("Order does not exist"));
  throw new Error("Order does not exist");
}
```

---

The same applies for `orderUser` and `requestUser`. The following line will crash unless you exit early when those variables are `null`.

> ```
> if (orderUser._id != requestUser._id) {
> ```